# dynamodb composite primary key design with multiple attributes

Tags: java, sql, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, rdbms

I am trying to design a dynamodb table to store data, in which multiple attributes constitutes as unique key. In this case how do I design a DynamoDBHashKey/primary key?

Currently I am thinking of combining different attributes with a separator and make it as primary key , is it right approach? During query all these attributes should be used in where conditions along with some other attributes, any assistance on this design?

I have 4 attributes joined like to form a unique primary key these `locationId + "_" + registerID + "_" + Date + "_" + sequenceNumber` and saving these 4 attributes separately also to assist in querying. I have one more normal attribute like `processedStatus` , which also needs to be added as filter parameter during query.

How do I design this table to execute below SQL like query i dynamodb?

```
select * from mytable where location=123 and registerid=45 and date>27-10-2022 12:10:23 and processedStatus=N
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
PK                                            SK
LocationID#123#RegisterId#45ProcessedStatus#N Date#<date>
```

Now when querying you can do a greater-than query where

PK is *LocationID#123#RegisterId#45ProcessedStatus#N*

SK is *the date*

Just pick date format that works well with Dynamo because you have to rely on lexicographic order here.

Comment: Do I need to have field-name along with value while storing data or just values with a delimiter will do? Also including ProcessedStatus as part of PK is it correct way, because once the record is processed I would like to update this field with a value Y, this is mainly used to avoid duplicate processing

Comment: Field name helps you determine what type of object you are dealing with when using  single table design. It's not mandatory but it helps a lot.


If the ProcessedStatus will be updated often then include it in the SK, then you can query for non-processed items with the "begins with" query.